# TikZ drawing arrows along multiple nodes

Tags: tikz-arrows

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, shape=circle] (n0) at (0,0) {0};
\node[draw, shape=circle] (n1) at (2,0) {1};
\node[draw, shape=circle] (n2) at (2,2) {2};
\node[draw, shape=circle] (n3) at (0,2) {3};

\draw[->] (n0) -- (n1);
\draw[->] (n1) -- (n2);
\draw[->] (n2) -- (n3);
\draw[->] (n3) -- (n0);      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The above is what I wanted, but I was wondering if there is a single-line solution for the same. I tried:

```latex
\draw[->] (n0) -- (n1) -- (n2) -- (n3) -- (n0);
```

But this gave an arrow tip at the end of the path only.

How can I draw the arrow tip for every edge?

Comment: Simple, with defining `edge` style.  For example: `every edge/.style = {->}`. That I can show you this, please extend your code fragment to an MWE!

Comment: @Zarko I added an MWE.

Comment: With a single line   `\draw[->]  (n0) edge (n1) (n1) edge (n2) (n2) edge (n3) (n3) edge (n0);`

Comment: @SimonDispa Thanks! Any method without repeating nodes?

Comment: `\draw[->]  (n0) edge(n1) edge[<-] (n3) (n2) edge (n3)  edge[<-] (n1); `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have an arrowhead on each edge, you have two choices :

- as you do in your MWE, or
- instead of `--`, use `edge` which defines style for example as is done in MWE below and for all edges and than for all edges use only one command `\draw`.

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
C/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=1em},
every edge/.style = {draw, -Straight Barb}
                        ]
\node [C] (n0) at (0,0) {0};
\node [C] (n1) at (2,0) {1};
\node [C] (n2) at (2,2) {2};
\node [C] (n3) at (0,2) {3};
    
\draw   (n0) edge (n1) 
        (n1) edge (n2) 
        (n2) edge (n3) 
        (n3) edge (n0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]